# Invalid PNG format in set-ui-customization in aws cognito

Tags: shell, png, blob, amazon-cognito

I am using below aws cli command to modify the UI.

```
aws cognito-idp set-ui-customization --user-pool-id us-west-2_XXXXXXX --client-id ALL  --css ".submitButton-customizable{background-color: #0091e1;} " --region us-west-2 --image-file Logo.png
```

But it is giving me an error that my PNG File is not valid.

I have seen the documentation and found that image-file should have file format `Base64-encoded binary data object`

I am using Linux Instance (Ubuntu) and running this command from terminal.

How can i correct this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem, try using the `fileb://./Logo.png` syntax with the `--image-file` flag, e.g.

```
aws cognito-idp set-ui-customization --user-pool-id us-west-2_XXXXXXX --client-id ALL  --css ".submitButton-customizable{background-color: #0091e1;} " --region us-west-2 --image-file fileb://./Logo.png
```

Comment: Perfect Answer!